# Bash script to parse XML color file

Tags: bash, shell-script, xml

I have an XML color file that I want to transform to a Kotlin equivalent. Given this input file

**colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Color Scheme -->
    <color name="primary">#YYYYYY</color>
    <color name="primary_variant">#ZZZZZZ</color>
    ...
</resources>
```

this is the output I'm looking for

**Colors.kt**

```
// Color Scheme
val primary = Color(0xFFYYYYYY)
val primaryVariant = Color(0xFFZZZZZZ)
...
```

I already put together a Python script to do it, but I was interested in the difference in complexity with a shell solution, which I'm not proficient enough to do.

Specifically, what I'm looking for is:

- Comments gets mapped to Kotlin comments
- Newlines are maintained, indentation isn't
- Variable names are converted from snake_case to camelCase

Comment: Are you sure about "pure bash"? This would mean not being able to even use `sed` or alike.

Comment: @FelixJN I'm not familiar with shell differences, my bad. Of course anything with `sed` or `awk` is fine

Comment: Use an xml parser like `xmlstarlet`, or an xml-parsing library for python.  1. shell is good for running and orchestrating programs that do text-processing (and other) work.  It is not good (in fact, it is terrible) at actually doing that work itself. 2. simple line-oriented tools like sed or awk, using regular expressions alone, are not adequate for parsing XML or other structure text - awk is capable of it, but you'll probably have to write your own xml parser - whereas other languages, like perl or python, already have parser libs written, tested, readily available, and in use for years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the XML document

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Color Scheme -->
    <color name="primary">#YYYYYY</color>
    <color name="primary_variant">#ZZZZZZ</color>
    <color name="primary_variant">#ZZZZZZ</color>
    <color name="primary_variant_old">#ZZZZZZ</color>
    <color name="primary_variant_new">#ZZZZZZ</color>
</resources>
```

in `file.xml`, you could use the `xq` utility to get the output you want like so:

```bsh
xq -r '.resources.color[] |
    "val " +
    ( ."@name" | gsub("_(?<a>.)"; .a | ascii_upcase) ) +
    " = Color(" +
    ( ."#text" | sub("#"; "0xFF") ) +
    ")"' file.xml
```

or, possibly easier to read,

```bsh
xq -r '.resources.color[] |
        [ ( ."@name" | gsub("_(?<a>.)"; .a | ascii_upcase) ),
          ( ."#text" | sub("#"; "0xFF") ) ] |
        "val " + .[0] + " = Color(" + .[1] + ")"' file.xml
```

This picks out each color entry and inserts the modified value of the `name` attribute and the `color` node's value into a string that is then outputted.

The `name` attribute is turned into camel-case by converting each `_x` (where `x` is any character) into `X` (upper-case `x`).  The `color` nodes value then gets its `#` replaced by `0xFF`.

This would output

```
val primary = Color(0xFFYYYYYY)
val primaryVariant = Color(0xFFZZZZZZ)
val primaryVariant = Color(0xFFZZZZZZ)
val primaryVariantOld = Color(0xFFZZZZZZ)
val primaryVariantNew = Color(0xFFZZZZZZ)
```

The `xq` utility is a tool for translation of XML into JSON.  The `xq` tool then becomes a wrapper around the well known `jq` JSON parser, so `jq` expressions may be used to modify or generally work with the XML document structure. It is part of the `yq` utility distribution (originally a YAML parser wrapper around `jq`), as found at https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/  (the `yq` utility available via `snap` on Linux is also a YAML parser, but a quite different tool!)

The `xq` parser, like most other parsers, discards comments.

---

For reference, this is the JSON document that `xq` converts the above XML into:

```json
{
  "resources": {
    "color": [
      {
        "@name": "primary",
        "#text": "#YYYYYY"
      },
      {
        "@name": "primary_variant",
        "#text": "#ZZZZZZ"
      },
      {
        "@name": "primary_variant",
        "#text": "#ZZZZZZ"
      },
      {
        "@name": "primary_variant_old",
        "#text": "#ZZZZZZ"
      },
      {
        "@name": "primary_variant_new",
        "#text": "#ZZZZZZ"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```